# Minhas perguntas são tão ruins assim?

Tags: debate

Eu gostaria de saber o que está de errado com minhas perguntas.

Na verdade, antigamente eu reclamava sempre dos downvotes, porque **aparentemente** a maioria era de implicância ou sei lá qual o motivo.

Mas agora, tentando levar os meus pensamentos para um lado bom e evitando pensar que seja má fé de algum usuário, eu tento imaginar que os downvotes poderia ser algo de errado com minha pergunta (ou resposta).

Estou deixando nos comentários algo como "me ajude a melhorar essa pergunta" ou "O que posso fazer para melhorar essa pergunta?".

Bem... Até agora não adiantou. Não houve respostas. Exceto que alguns casos até removeram o downvote (casos raros).

Mas eu queria entender se realmente as minhas perguntas estão:

1 - Não mostra esforço de pesquisa

2 - Não é clara

3- Não é útil

Vamos aos exemplos dessa última semana. O que há de errado nessas perguntas, por exemplo?

- [O que é Engenharia Reversa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112817/o-que-%C3%A9-engenharia-reversa)
- [Como escapar o caractere de porcentagem (%) no LIKE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113599/como-escapar-o-caractere-de-porcentagem-no-like)
- [Qual é a definição de Aprendizado de Máquina (Machine Learning)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113343/qual-%C3%A9-a-defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-aprendizado-de-m%C3%A1quina-machine-learning)
- [Como usar os argumentos passados para um script python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113327/como-usar-os-argumentos-passados-para-um-script-python)
- [Qual é o significado da palavra "cout" no C/C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113302/qual-%C3%A9-o-significado-da-palavra-cout-no-c-c)
- [Qual é a diferença entre um mixin e uma function em SASS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112485/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-mixin-e-uma-function-em-sass)
- [Como criar uma lista de datas do ano em php, pulando os finais de semana?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111656/como-criar-uma-lista-de-datas-do-ano-em-php-pulando-os-finais-de-semana)

**Nota**: Não quero ganhar votos em nenhuma das perguntas só porque foram postadas aqui no meta, mas quero entender o que está acontecendo.

A frequência que estou recebendo desses votos é que me intriga: Fiz algum comentário que não deveria para alguém? Ou realmente, essas perguntas não prestam para estar no site? É claro, algumas receberam muitos votos positivos, mas tendo ali um negativo (e pensando teoricamente que a pergunta está ruim para a análise de alguém), eu gostaria de saber o que poderia ser melhorado - é claro, se realmente o motivo do downvote é por que a pergunta tem um detalhe errado.

E para complementar: Perguntar coisas aparentemente fáceis é proibido? Quer dizer fáceis para mim, porque para alguém pode não ser tão fácil assim.

Comment: Já sabes que deve ser mesmo represálias...

Comment: @JorgeB.  mas fui instruído a não pensar que todos os casos são assim. O Gabe me falou isso, e ele tem razão. Nem sempre que dizer que são represálias. Mas com tanta frequência eu quero saber se minha interpretação está errada ou não (penso que nesses casos são represálias). Dar upvotes na pergunta para "compensar" os downvotes não vai resolver. O que quero saber é o motivo que isso vem acontecendo frequentemente. Talvez eu precise tratar alguém de maneira mais educada... Vai saber,  né

Comment: Não quer dizer que são represálias, mas que parece, parece.

Comment: Eu ia fazer a mesma pergunta ontem acredita, mas iria ser um pouco diferente, no meu caso não ganho muitos downvotes, mas também não ganho upvotes. Eu posso estar viajando, mas acho que o problema não é up ou down, fechar, ser tão claro ou não, acho que talvez seja algo como:  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4871/3635 (a leitura é longa e chata, eu coloquei dois locais escritos "resumindo", se tiver preguiça leia direto os resumos). Talvez nessa resposta eu não tenha conseguido me expressar direito, mas a raiz de vários problemas me parece se esse.

Comment: Acho que todas estão dentro do escopo. Eu pelo menos não faço distinção de perguntas fáceis/difíceis porque isso depende da experiência de quem as visualiza. Uma pergunta como a do `cout` pode ser inútil para quem programa há anos, mas pode ser importante para um iniciante. Esse negócio de "*se tivesse procurado no Google antes de perguntar...*" que alguns usuários levam em consideração é um câncer para o site, sério. Mas eu tenho uma dúvida também, por que você [faz perguntas já pensando no downvote](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27620714#27620714)?

Comment: Já agora já tens um -1 aqui, só assim...

Comment: Eu já fiz algumas perguntas que parecem ser fácil de encontrar a resposta, para mim isso não é motivo de downvote, mais nem todo mundo pensa igual eu. As vezes alguém esta pensando que você não se esforça nas perguntas (mera especulação, pode ser outra coisa), porem, suas perguntas não tem problema nenhum e eu percebi que você esta recebendo pelo menos um downvote em cada pergunta, da a impressão que alguém não gosta de você.

Comment: As suas perguntas são excelentes. Bem formatadas, simples de entender, objetivas. Acredito que os downvotes é devido ao que foi descrito na resposta do @Zignd.

Comment: Se não tiver comentário contrutivo explicando, eu não levaria a sério

Answer (score 7):

Esta resposta se baseia na pergunta: *Qual é a definição de Aprendizado de Máquina (Machine Learning)?* (que eu respondi)

> Ou realmente, essas perguntas não prestam para estar no site?

Acredito que ela "presta" sim:

[dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> 3- Não é útil

Acho útil, pois:

- é um tema importante
- está relacionado a programação
- provavelmente servirá como referência para muitas pessoas que venham a consultar as respostas

> 2 - Não é clara

O texto parece bem claro.

> 1 - Não mostra esforço de pesquisa

Talvez o problema esteja aqui.

Dois pontos importantes:

- Cada autor redige o texto conforme a sua percepção pessoal da dúvida, e cada leitor interpreta esse texto de uma forma diferente
- O que é fácil para mim (que estou lendo), nem sempre é fácil para todo mundo (que está perguntando)

Ao ler a sua pergunta, me pareceu bem claro o tipo de informação que você esperava e ao responder, procurei atender a sua espectativa.

Mas a interpretação do texto é bem pessoal e a causa dos *downvotes* pode estar aí.

Exemplo de formas diferentes de redação (ainda levando em consideração a pergunta acima):

1. "Gostaria de uma explanação mais detalhada a respeito do assunto:"
2. "Após pesquisar, encontrei alguns algoritmos como: Redes neurais, Random Forests, Máquinas de vetores de suporte. Mas gostaria de uma explanação mais detalhada a respeito do assunto:"

No caso `2`, "eu" (autor) não estudei durante "dias" ou "semanas" o que são "Redes neurais, Random Forests, Máquinas de vetores de suporte", caso contrário "eu" já teria entendido sobre o assunto e não faria muito sentido perguntar, pois não teria dúvidas (sobre o conceito).

Apenas fiz uma busca rápida sobre o assunto e mudei a redação da pergunta.

Mas para quem está lendo, a forma `2` transmite uma "sensação" de que "eu" me esforcei, mas não consegui entender exatamente como esses conceitos funcionam, por isso estou pedindo a ajuda da comunidade.

Answer (score 6):

Eu chutaria que o motivo seria esse mesmo, perguntas fáceis demais, que poderiam ser respondidas com uma simples pesquisa na internet, mas infelizmente não tem como saber o motivo. As pessoas simplesmente downvotam e não são obrigadas a detalharem o porquê.

Bom, é basicamente isso que me parece, mas eu não frequento muito o lado do site que você frequenta, monitoro apenas as perguntas voltadas a .NET e algumas coisas de JavaScript.

Comment: Zignd, acho que falar das tags seria um comentário infeliz (para justificar os downvotes). Porque duas perguntas com a tag `terminologia` receberam downvotes.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters O problema é que não tem como saber quem deu os downvotes, o que resta para você é se contentar com a situação atual e se realmente estiver ocorrendo um abuso aguardar para que o próprio sistema da StackExchange corrija, Ele consegue identificar abusos de downvotes, e os anula quando isso ocorre.

Comment: Só consegue detectar quando é em sequência. Quem dera detectasse a intenção! rsrsrsrs.

Comment: É, nesse seu caso realmente fica difícil.

Comment: Eu gosto muito de terminologia, a pergunta pode de inicio ser fácil de saber a resposta, mas aqui é uma comunidade voltada a trazer conteudo de "qualidade" e "concentrar" respostas para vários problemas e é isso que as pessoas não entendem, elas pensam que é um site para resolver problemas momentâneos, sendo que as respostas aqui são totalmente para incentivar um local de fonte mais confiavel e de fácil pesquisa. O problema é que o pessoal não entende isso (enfrentei um problema parecido no portugues.stackexchange).