# Downvotes com comentários linkados

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Ao notar tantas reclamações e sugestões e mesmo que digam que é o crescimento da comunidade parece estar um tanto evidente que os votos não são bem usados por uma parte dos usuários e aqueles que sabem votar ficam com medo de comentar (justificar) votos negativos com medo de retaliação (*serial downvoter*), alguns exemplos das ultimas semanas:

- Surgiram sugestões de [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso) para tentar resolver o suposto problema:

  - [Notificação de votos negativos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4863/notifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-votos-negativos)
  - [Deveríamos qualificar os votos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4865/dever%C3%ADamos-qualificar-os-votos)
  - [Votos negativos deveriam ter custo mais alto?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4857/votos-negativos-deveriam-ter-custo-mais-alto)
- E também ouve duvidas para entender o suposto aumento:

  - [O que está acontecendo com os votos negativos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4800/o-que-est%C3%A1-acontecendo-com-os-votos-negativos)
  - [Minhas perguntas são tão ruins assim?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/minhas-perguntas-s%C3%A3o-t%C3%A3o-ruins-assim)
  - [Quem está votando?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4889/quem-est%C3%A1-votando) (esse é meio que uma sugestão [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso), mas parece ser mais voltado a uma duvida)

A minha sugestão para não *apenas* coibir o mal uso, mas também para fazer nós que queremos dar criticas construtivas e justificar o downvote seria um comentário padrão ou customizado *anonimo* semelhante a janela de fechamento, a ideia não é reduzir os downvotes, mas na verdade tornar evidentes os votos negativos que são justos sem parecer que eles foram arbitrários (eu mesmo gostaria de saber os problemas nas minhas postagens com votos negativos para poder melhorá-las e até removê-las se necessário).

Seria assim:

- No momento que clico em negativar, aparece uma janela assim (suponha que ele selecionou a primeira opção):

  <kbd>[image: Justificar downvote]</kbd>
- Após o downvote o comentário ficaria anonimo e ficaria assim:

  <kbd>[image: comentário anonimo]</kbd>
- Se outro usuário vier a votar também e selecionar a mesma opção (Código não funciona) então não será adicionado um novo comentário, ambos downvotes ficarão vinculados ao mesmo comentário e ele ficará assim:

  <kbd>[image: comentário anonimo agrupado]</kbd>
- Se um terceiro usuário votar e selecionar a opção **Mal escrito**, então ficará assim:

  <kbd>[image: comentário anonimo]</kbd>
- Se um quarto usuário votar e selecionar ultima opção (do campo de texto) ele poderá digitar um comentário personalizado e anonimo.

Desta forma o usuário iria poder se expressar sem ter medo de sofrer ataques de pessoas imaturas que não entendem bem o sistema ou que se acham injustificadas e começam a dar downvotes gratuitos.

Outra opção também seria poder reverter os downvotes, mas somente em último caso, a ideia seria uma *flag* que abriria um pop-up e quem discorda dos votos negativos poderia talvez mandar para a **[fila de analise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)** (usuários com 500 pontos podem analisar) e lá seria julgado se os votos fazem sentido, uma espécie de triagem.

Nessa *triagem* seria no minimo 3 de 5 votos para reverter os downvotes, se houver 3 votos pra reverter o "comentário anonimo" ligado ao downvote seria removido junto, se forem 2 votos pra reverter e 3 para manter, então nada acontece.

*(note que os comentários ainda seriam anônimos mesmo pra quem tem acesso a fila, eles só participariam da triagem)*

A tela seria algo como:

<kbd>[image: triagem de votos]</kbd>

Comment: A ideia é boa, mas quem iria avaliar essa triagem? Pergunto isso porque imagino que você iria sugerir os usuários mais experientes e com maior reputação, e temos a fila de fechamento que está meio congestionada esses dias(a tendencia talvez é que fique mais).

Comment: Eu ainda não consegui desenhar (imaginar) todas as telas, dentro do possivel irei atualizar a sugestão ;)

Comment: Outra nota os comentários prontos são "exemplos apenas".

Comment: Essa não é a mesma ideia que a do utluiz?

Comment: [Deveríamos qualificar os votos?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4865/dever%C3%ADamos-qualificar-os-votos)

Comment: Acho a iniciativa de modo geral bem legal, mas um comentário automático genérico não iria minimizar os down, primeiro porque quem vota down poderia usar um motivo subjetivo, tipo "não é útil", e isso para a **pessoa** que votou pode realmente não ser para especificamente **ela** e para todos os demais seria útil, nesse caso é justo reverter o voto desta pessoa? Vamos a um outro exemplo, **não demonstra esforço de pesquisa** as vezes a pessoa é tão perdida no assunto que não consegue fazer o básico de pesquisa sobre um assunto nesse caso não seria falta de esforço apenas ignorância pura.

Comment: @JorgeB. Parecida, mas **não** é a mesma, os comentários aqui são anônimos e linkados entre vários usuários que negativaram pelo mesmo motivo para evitar parecer SPAM acaso existam muitos comentários e contem a sugestão de fila de analise e aqui não tem "notificações" o que eu sugeri foi a "triagem". Eu pensei em postar como resposta lá, mas aqui é um sugestão bem diferente no final. Ainda tenho detalhes a adicionar, mas ser criativo do dia pra noite pra desenhar todas as telas fica dificil. Prometo adicionar mais detalhes o quanto antes possivel ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas pelo menos devias fazer uma referência a resposta dela na tua pergunta, para que elas fiquem linkadas.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA em nenhum momento eu quis reduzir os negativos, o que eu quero de verdade é fazer o usuário se sentir confortável em justificar o downvote sem ter medo de ser perseguido por **"serial downvoters"**, pois é anonimo e quanto a diminuir eu acho que talvez venha a aumentar, mas serão votos com maior qualidade e mais úteis. Quem vai definir se o downvote pode ser revertido serão mais de uma pessoa, igual a maioria das ferramentas na **fila de analise** (acredito que você já deve ter usado). Será necessário minimo de 3 a 5 votos de usuários que não deram downvote. A comunidade decide :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu sei, estava a falar duma referência à resposta, mas é só a minha opinião.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim é isso.

Comment: Comentário proprio: fheifjfneifhgjdjvhbheueiehgnvnfjeivjeifnvhwiwifjvnvnekvnvjfnvnfjejfujtgntjrj

Comment: @brasofilo triagem e reversão :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento quem poderia reverter um voto negativo com um comentário tipo: **não é útil ao meu ver**?

Comment: @SneepSNinjA usuários que acessam a fila de analise, o processo seria feito pela comunidade, que acessa a fila de analise tem que ter uma pontuação mais elevada. Com 500 pontos já é possivel acessar, mas só duas opções (eu acho), com 5k ou 10k seria interessante pra poder acessar esta fila especifica. O que acha?

Comment: Acho que entendi onde quer chegar, se for só para evitar o **serial downvoter** então o voto aberto resolveria(lista com nomes de quem votou), sem necessariamente justificar, pois o **serial downvoter** poderia dar justificativas neutras e continuaria a perseguição entre usuários acho que o voto aberto seria a melhor solução, justificar o voto sei lá, eu acho que da margem para respostas neutras que seria impossível uma reversão do voto.

Comment: Eu gosto da ideia dos comentários anônimos, mas a pessoa que escreveu um comentário tem que ficar registrada no sistema (mesmo que ninguém saiba quem ela é), porque se o comentário é ofensivo ou inútil ele deve poder ser **Sinalizado**, e, neste caso, os moderadores podem saber quem o fez para contactar essa pessoa, afim de que ela não fique impune. Ou seja, o autor do comentário anônimo é revelado aos moderadores apenas se for constatado que o comentário é ofensivo/inútil/spam.

Answer (score 4):

**Discordo.**

A pergunta começa com uma opinião não substanciada por nenhum exemplo sólido no site principal:

> parece estar um tanto evidente que os votos não são bem usados por uma parte dos usuários

Creio que o meta-drama de alguns poucos usuários assíduos não implica um fenômeno global.

Me parece uma complicação extrema ficar explicando uma porcaria dum simples voto. Isto não é o Prêmio Nobel e já temos suficiente com analisar, editar, filtrar, votar, comentar de bom coração... enfim, moderar um monte de conteúdo alheio.

Comentários são um sub-produto do site, seu status é de **"conteúdo de segunda-classe"**, e, se tivermos que jogar isso numa fila de análise, vai ser tipo estudar Gases Intestinais quando podiamos estar estudando Alimentação Saudável.

Essa história de que o voto negativo "precisa de conserto" (o novo meme do SOpt) é muito simples de resolver: **me dá uma lista onde aparecem os posts que foram editados depois do meu voto, adoraria rever uns quantos**. <sup>**[*]**</sup>

O **medo de comentar** também é simples de resolver: nosso comentário deve se concentrar em como a pessoa pode melhorar seu post. Ponto. Se for usar algum adjetivo, que seja positivo. Só criticar ou linkar pro FAQ é fácil, mas no fim oferecer uma dica útil também é fácil. Talvez um smilie no fim do comentário dissipe qualquer má-interpretação ;)

Ficar choramingando porque `"Nossa! Minha pergunta/resposta é tão legal, tinha X votos positivos e Zero negativos, e agora tem Um negativo"`... bah, give me a break.

Dica de veterano: se algum dos seus posts estava em 0 e tomou um voto de vingança, esse mesmo post vai ser o alvo preferido pro seguinte voto de vingança (obviamente, de outra pessoa). Esse é o preço a pagar por verbalizar certas coisas. Façam o favor de engolir o orgulho e assumir o prejuizo (ridículo, no [grande esquema das coisas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)). O sistema automático não registra isso, reclamar com os moderadores não vai adiantar nada, abrir uma meta pergunta é perda de tempo.

<sup>**[*]**</sup>
<sup>- [Notification on edit of downvoted content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252055/1287812)</sup>
<sup>- [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/185667)</sup>

Comment: Eu nunca reclamei com moderadores e também não acho que agi com orgulho, eu apenas penso que usuários que realmente colaboraram as vezes ficam desanimados e desmotivados. Tudo bem eu sei que vocês terão uma série de justificavas que eu concordarei plenamente, pode ter certeza. Então vou fazer assim, vou presumir que sua resposta foi para um contexto geral e os motivos que citei não são o suficiente para essa mudança drástica no sistema e que ideia não é ruim, apenas não tem motivos suficientes para fazer essa mudança. Espero que entenda que escrevi de uma maneira com as melhores das intenções!

Comment: Parte da resposta tem até bons argumentos, mas em alguns trechos foi de extremo mau gosto e ofensivo. Sem contar os comentários com certo tom de "chacota". Pensei que o SO fosse um tipo de ambiente diferenciado, não um ambiente como fóruns, onde o fato de discordar da opinião de alguém fosse motivo para fazer piada desta. É por essas e outras que mesmo tendo mil e uma idéias e mil e uma duvidas, prefiro guardar muitas pra mim mesmo do que me arriscar postando tudo aqui e receber esse tipo de resposta, ainda mais de um usuário "veterano"(voltamos pra escola, é isso?).

Comment: Outra, o fato de discordar não da o direito a ninguém de fazer pouco caso com a opinião alheia.

Comment: **1**) O tom de "chacota" foi feito por **mim** direcionado a **mim**, minhas duas primeiras questões no meta foram sobre down vote!!! Se ler meu comentários, verás que sempre saio em defesa de quem recebe *down vote*! Desde que me cadastrei, dei apenas 2 negativos e sempre que me é possível, justifico o *-1* alheio mesmo correndo o risco de cair na malha fina. **2**) Compartilhe suas idéias meu jovem, as minhas já receberam tanto *down vote* que eu ficaria devendo pontos. **Não faça disso uma desavença** :)

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento já que meu comentário se foi pela má interpretação, espero que tenha deixado o motivo no comentário acima. Não era minha intenção que meu comentário fosse interpretado como piada, mas me retrato publicamente com um singelo pedido de desculpas, e a quem mais tenha achado ofensivo. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, esqueci de colocar um adendo marcando meu respeito e admiração total a sua participação no site.

Comment: @PapaCharlie de minha parte pode ter certeza que não levei pra lado mal ninguém, meu único receio era que eu tivesse falado algo que fosse mal interpretado, não sou muito bom as vezes pra escrever e fazer o texto ficar claro. Mas pode ter certeza que eu sempre sigo o *be-nice* :D ... e também nunca sou de opinião absoluta, sempre deixo um espaço na minha cabeça pra tentar ver a opinião dos demais e muitas vezes mudo de ideia, mas sempre tentando ir pro melhor para todos. Obrigado mesmo por compartilhar.

Comment: @brasofilo também admiro você e sua participação, é um dos poucos que noto participar e se interessar nos debates do meta no soen e as vezes no METÃO. Não acho que seja necessário uma nota sobre mim eu apenas queria ter certeza que eu me expressei de maneira correta, porque como eu disse pro PapaCharlie, nunca sou de opinião absoluta, sei que sou humano e que erro e sempre vou errar e que posso ter afirmado algo que não era uma verdade, sendo assim vou editar o meu texto para não causar esse tom meio estranho que deixei... E tenha certeza que sua resposta eu levei totalmente pro lado bom! :)

Comment: "me dá uma lista onde aparecem os posts que foram editados depois do meu voto, adoraria rever uns quantos". +1 por isso :)

Comment: @Diego, você pode vocalizar sua opinião de maneira mais completa através de uma resposta. O fato de eu ser "veterano" só significa que já li, votei, participei bem mais que outras pessoas; não faz de mim melhor nem pior que ninguém; nem minha opinião mais importante, mas o "calouro" vai precisar se esforçar bem mais pra argumentar comigo. Por favor, não é minha intenção "detonar" nenhuma pessoa, mas se alguém vem com uma idéia que não concordo, não vou morder a língua pra não fazer críticas duras e sempre tentando não ser grosseiro. Às vezes dá errado, sorry :)